# How to access cookie in nuxt fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js

I am looking for way to access cookie in my nuxt fetch. Here is my code;

```
async fetch() {
    const { store, route } = this.$nuxt.context
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.baseUrl}/user-saved-homes/?ordering=${route.query.ordering}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Token ' + my_token,
        },
      }
    )
    store.commit('ADD_SAVED_HOMES', data.results)
  },
```

I need fetch because I was access to `$fetchState.pending`. But I have tried looking for a way to access cookie in the nuxt fetch, but I haven't found any. Please, I need help here

Comment: where is the cookie you want to access? already existing? or is it a cookie set in the response to this code?

Comment: Already existing token, stored in the browser cookies, when user login or register

Answer (score 0):

Since fetch by default runs on the server, I can't use js-cookies(javascript library), to get the token. So the best way to make this happen is for nuxt fetch to run on the client side.
So adding `fetchOnServer: false` enabled me to use js-cookies to get the token

so my code is now;

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookies'
export default {
  async fetch() {
    const { store, route } = this.$nuxt.context
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.baseUrl}/user-saved-homes/`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Token ' + Cookies.getItem('token'),
        },
      }
    )
    store.commit('ADD_SAVED_HOMES', data.results)
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
}
```